# Remove parameters from url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to remove parameters from url,

I need change this:

http://example.com/?page=about

To this:

http://example.com/about

How?

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

#Remove php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
#rewrite /about to /?page=about    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

this will rewrite

```
 /about
```

to

```
 /?page=about
```

Comment: Top part of your code is removing php extension. what do u mean by "not working"?

Comment: I got message in google chrome "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: I have edited my ans, dont append it to your code, try it seperatly

Comment: Thanks for edit but when I open my link like this: http://example.com/about
my about page is not working :(

Comment: I need change ?page=about   to  /about

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Working, but remove .php format not working, please read my code at the top.

Comment: Your question says change this to that, now you say remove this please clarify your question better.